# how to include npm packages using bower?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, gruntjs, npm, bower

I'm starting to develop ember using a grunt/bower workflow.

Many of the ember extensions seem to be in github as npm packages - what's the best practice way to add these to my project using bower?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit

Comment: that looks good - but how would i include eg. this https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth?

Answer (score 1):

The question suggest to use packages in not proper way.

If you want add npm packages you should use **npm manager** and **package.json** file – example https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#examples